# Adding onClick to RecyclerView Android

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I have put together some code as shown below which gets data from a JSON file hosted on a server and puts it into a RecyclcerView. This has been working fine but any way I try to add a click method it does not work. I am looking to make it so that if I click one of the rows it will tell me the country it is. I have no idea where I am going wrong but I will attach my code below which gets the JSON data and puts it into the RecyclerView.

Thanks

```
package com.example.curtisboylan.myapplication;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;


import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;

public class MainRecycler extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ArrayList countries;
    private static String url = "http://curtisboylan.me/mygeek/mygeektest.php";

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        countries = new ArrayList<>();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_recycler);
        initViews();
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String message = bundle.getString("message");
        TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        if (Objects.equals(message, "di1")){
            txtView.setText("Diagnostics");
        }
        else if (Objects.equals(message, "screen1")){
            txtView.setText("Screen Repair");
        }

        setTitle("Available Technicians");
    }
    private void initViews(){
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainRecycler.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("MyGeek");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String name = c.getString("name");
                        //String email = c.getString("email");
                        //String address = c.getString("address");
                        //String gender = c.getString("gender");

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                       // JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                       // String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
                       // String home = phone.getString("home");
                       // String office = phone.getString("office");

                        countries.add(c.getString("name"));

                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.hide();

            RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);

            RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new DataAdapter(countries);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Try this, I have explained in detail how to handle this. http://blog.inapptext.com/recyclerview-creating-dynamic-lists-and-grids-in-android-1/#responding_user_actions

Comment: In your DataAdapter in need declared onClickListener to any component, and maybe send this action to mainActivity with interface event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a click listener on the Recycler view, try adding click listener in the adapter class, in the onBindViewHolder method. That is how you will get the exact item on which the click was executed.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Viewholder holder, final int position) {
    YourClassObject item = YourClassObjectList.get(position);

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Recycle Click" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a interface in your Adapter class

```
public interface EventsCatalogsAdapter{
    void onClickImageCategory(Catalogs catalog);
}
```

Create a atribute of EventsCatalogsAdapter

```
 private EventsCatalogsAdapter event;
```

Create constructor

```
public CatalogsAdapter(EventsCatalogsAdapter event) {
    this.event        = event;
}
```

Add setOnClickListener in **onBindViewHolder**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final CatalogsViewHolder holder, final int position){
    holder.imageCatalog.setOnClickListener(holder);
}
```

In you **RecyclerView.ViewHolder** implements onClickListener event.

```
 class CatalogsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        private ImageView imageCatalog;
        private TextView tvCatalogName;
        private View vLegendCatalog;

        public CatalogsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageCatalog   = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.i =vCatalogItem);
            tvCatalogName  = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCatalogName);
            vLegendCatalog = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vLegendCatalog);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            event.onClickImageCategory(catalogsList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
        }
    }
```